# Find correlation between two sets of categorical data

Tags: r, categorical-data

The question is whether we can find a correlation between two sets of grades (categorical data).

Let’s say we have a dog competition and there are 1000 dogs participating.

There are two rounds of assessment

first round
dog owners give their assessment on the scale from A to C. Where A is excellent and C is bad. There are four criteria for assessment during both tours (behaviour etc).

second round
one judge gives his assessment of one dog based on the same assessment criteria as in round 1. however, grades vary from M - meeting expectation, E - exceeding expectation, B - Bellow expectation.

We understand that M is B, E is A and B is C.

After two rounds our table would look like:

```
| dog             | round one | round two |
| --------------- | --------- | --------- |
| Dog1_criteria1  | A         | B         |
| Dog1_criteria2  | A         | E         |
| Dog1_criteria3  | A         | E         |
| Dog1_criteria4  | B         | M         |
| Dog2_criteria1  | A         | E         |
| Dog2_criteria2  | B         | M         |
| Dog2_criteria3  | A         | E         |
| Dog2_criteria4  | C         | B         |
....
```

How do we find a correlation between the two sets of answers? Thank you!

Comment: I guess this is more of an stats question, flagging it for stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: R based solution strategy: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/893/how-to-get-correlation-between-two-categorical-variable-and-a-categorical-variab  Good idea to do a web search first.